# WebForms label text is not updated from OnInit()

Tags: vb.net, webforms

I have a WebForms application. Among other things, it has a Search box, a repeater, and a label totalItems that displays the count of the items in the repeater. The repeater is populated in a method called from Page_Init() method, based on a text entered into the Search control. For some reason, if I run the application with nothing in the Search control, and then second time with a text in the Search control, the content of the repeater changes accordingly, but the totalItems label is not updated. I debugged it and know that totalItems.Text is set to the correct value.

Here is the code:

In .aspx:

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="makeblock">
            <asp:Label ID="totalItems" CssClass="totalItems" Runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In .aspx.cs:

```
Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Init
    InitializeComponent()

    If Not IsNothing(Request.QueryString("group")) Then
        buildTable(CInt(Request.QueryString("cat")), CInt(Request.QueryString("group")), CurrentPage)
    End If
End Sub

Sub buildTable(ByVal itemCat As Integer, ByVal itemGroup As Integer, Optional ByVal pageNo As Integer = 1)
    ...
  totalItems.Text = "Total Items: " & numItems.ToString()
    ...
  itemRepeater.DataSource = pageds
    itemRepeater.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: You should be using the `Page_Load()` event because the label hasn't been fully initialized at the point where `Page_Init()` is called

Comment: @derekmckinnon I wish I could use Page_Load, but there is a reason why it is in Page_Init(). And it did populate the label correctly first time.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the reason you have to use init? Trying to rack my brain for another reason why you'd have stale label text...other than some weird ViewState thing.

Comment: @derekmckinnon The repeater is generated in the buildTable() method. If it is called from Page_Load(), for some reason it gets emptied.

Comment: That sounds really strange...have you tried stepping through the code (when it was `Page_Load()`) and checking the values in `pageds`? Checking that the `QueryString` values are expected? Coming from a C# background, I always use `int.TryParse` on `int` QS params, not sure what quirks `CInt` has.

Comment: Typically whenever I've seen a repeater losing data it's been because of `Postback` issues. Not sure if that applies to anything you are doing for this page, though.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. I meant, if I enter a quantity into a corresponding field in the repeater, and then press "Add to cart", there is nothing to add, as the repeater is rebuilt in Page_Load() and thus whatever the user entered is gone.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like it could be that you are not guarding the method with an `IsPostback` check to prevent re-populating the repeater.

Comment: I tried it, and it doesn't overwrite the repeater on pressing Add to Cart. But if I make a search, the label still doesn't update its value. Moreover, as the paging is built in the buildTable() method based on the number of records, if it is not a postback, no pages are created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185172/discussion-between-derekmckinnon-and-david-shochet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up some suggestions from the comments and discussion:

Generally speaking you should use the `Page_Load()` method as it ensures that all your page controls are properly loaded. Furthermore, you should guard your `Page_Load()` method with a check of the `IsPostBack` property to prevent re-populating your `Repeater` accidentally when handling another event, such as an `OnItemCommand` event from the repeater itself.

To help improve the architecture and to possibly expose some of the reasons why things are not updating as expected, I would suggest you separate the database operations, repeater population, and label updates into different methods. Then have a method that composes them together, calling them in proper sequence.

As for paging the repeater...the repeater is a very basic control that requires a lot of effort to do custom things with...the Web Forms event lifecycle can trip up even the most experienced of people. My suggestion would be to look into other SO questions about doing custom paging with repeater or other resources on the web to make sure you don't go down a path to insanity. You may find that something like a `DataGrid` could get the job done, although it is opinionated in its output and formatting.